# Sequel - Query Many to Many Associations

Tags: ruby, json, associations, sequel

I am having issues constructing the proper models, associations, and query for the following scenario and then returning results as JSON using Sequel with Ruby.

The database structure___

You can create a list of books. Each library contains books. Defined by the following:

```
db.create_table(:books) do
  primary_key :id
  String :name
  String :author
  DateTime :created
end

db.create_table(:libraries) do
  primary_key :id
  String :name
  String :city
  String :state
  DateTime :created
end

db.create_table(:libraries_books) do
  Integer :library_id
  Integer :book_id
  primary_key [:library_id, :book_id]
end


class Library < Sequel::Model(:libraries)

  many_to_many :libraries_books, :left_key=>:library_id, :right_key=>:book_id, :join_table=>:libraries_books
  one_to_many  :libraries_books, :key=>:library_id

end

class LibraryBook < Sequel::Model(:libraries_books)

  many_to_one  :libraries
  many_to_one  :books

end
```

I am trying to determine the correct way to access all the book names for a given library. I initially tried to follow the Sequel Associations guide but was not able to figure out how I could use LibraryBook with associations to get all the books for a library and join on the Book model to get the proper columns.

After getting stuck with some of the methods described, I attempted to create my own query as such:

```
LibraryBook.select(:books.*)
           .join_table(:inner, :libraries, :id => :library_id)
           .join_table(:inner, :books, :id => :book_id)
           .where(:library_id => 1)
```

Which seems to get me partially there. However, when I use the serialization extension, I get an error when the results are being converted:

```
undefined method `book_id' for #<LibraryGame:0x007fa9e904b470>
```

Any insight into that can be provided would be very helpful!

Comment: You don't show the code that uses the serialization plugin, or the full backtrace of the error, and it's hard to give useful help without that information.

Answer (score 7):

Try the following:

```
db.create_table(:books) do
  primary_key :id
  String :name
  String :author
  DateTime :created
end

db.create_table(:libraries) do
  primary_key :id
  String :name
  String :city
  String :state
  DateTime :created
end

db.create_table(:books_libraries) do
  foreign_key :library_id, :libraries, key: :id
  foreign_key :book_id, :books, key: :id, index: true
  primary_key [:library_id, :book_id]
end


class Library < Sequel::Model
  many_to_many :books
end

class Book < Sequel::Model
  many_to_many :libraries
end
```

Note renaming the `libraries_books` table to `books_libraries` and the use of the foreign_key directive for referential integrity. Conventions should allow things to just work.

```
Library[7].books  # returns all books for library '7'
```

Or alternatively:

```
Book.where(libraries: Library[7])
```

Or multiple libraries:

```
Book.where(libraries: Library.where(id: [3,7,9]))
```

If sequel is not able to do the inflection for Library/Libraries then you may need to add your own [inflection rule](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Inflections.html), eg:

```
Sequel.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'Library', 'Libraries'
end
```